# Constrain parameter to be some finite union of literal values, when mix-ins are in use

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, union-types

I need a way to constrain the parameter of a generic function to a union of literal values, that is,

- `'foo'`, `'foo' | 'bar'`, `42`, etc. must be allowed
- `string` or `number` must not
- `string & SomethingElse` or `number & AnotherThing` must also not
- `('foo' | 'bar') & SomethingElse`, `42 & AnotherThing` should be allowed (less important)

Consider a function like this

```
declare function test<K extends string>(t: { [P in K]: string; }): void;
```

The idea is that we want every possible value of `K` to have a corresponding property in `t`, so that we can look up values in `t` based on some `K`-typed values.

Some example usages showing everything going well:

```
declare const foobar: { foo: 'bar'; };
test(foobar); // compiles, correct
test<'foo'>(foobar); // compiles, correct
test<'bar'>(foobar); // compiler error, correct
//          ^^^^^^
// Argument of type '{ foo: "bar"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ bar: string; }'.
//  Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ foo: "bar"; }' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.
```

However, there is a problem:

```
test<string>(foobar); // compiles, INCORRECT
```

In the `test<string>` case, `{ [P in K]: string; }` becomes `{ [P: string]: string; }`, which does not guarantee that there is actually a key at every value (and indeed, that would be impossible, barring some proxy getter shenanigans). I therefore do not want to allow `{ [P: string]: string; }` arguments in my `test` function, which is equivalent to saying I do not want my `test` function to allow `string` as the value for `K`.

Now, one *can* get around this—kind of. Consider

```
declare function test<K extends string>(t: string extends K ? never : { [P in K]: string; }): void;
```

The `string extends K` test tells us if `string` has been passed to `K`, and in such a case we make the argument `never`, preventing any real values from being passed to the function (it would be better to raise an error here, but Typescript does not support that). And so

```
test<string>(foobar); // compiler error, correct
//           ^^^^^^
// Argument of type '{ foo: "bar"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

**However**, this doesn’t solve the problem when we use string mix-ins, which our project does. Consider

```
type StringExtended = string & { extension(): void; };
test<StringExtended>(foobar); // compiles, INCORRECT
```

Since `string extends StringExtended` is false, our `never` hack isn’t applied, and we are back to `{ [P in K]: string; }`, which oddly enough is now inferred as `{}` rather than `{ [P: string]: string; }`. Either way, though, it still compiles. I do not want it to, because our project uses a lot of these kinds of extensions (specifically using [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal)), and it is all too plausible for some `K extends string` constraint that was meant for string literals to instead accept these kinds of string extensions, breaking the type-safety of the function.

For a slightly more “realistic” example, consider

```
interface Keyed<K extends string, D> { key: K; data: D; }

function toNameOf<K extends string>(
    { key }: Keyed<K, any>,
    names: string extends K ? never : { [P in K]: string; },
): string {
    return names[key];
}

declare const k1: Keyed<'foo' | 'bar', number>;
toNameOf(k1, { foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar' });
toNameOf(k1, {});
//           ^^
toNameOf(k1, { foo: 'Foo' });
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
toNameOf(k1, { bar: 'Bar' });
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

declare const k2: Keyed<string, number>;
toNameOf(k2, { foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar' });
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
toNameOf(k2, {});
//           ^^
toNameOf(k2, { foo: 'Foo' });
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
toNameOf(k2, { bar: 'Bar' });
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

declare const k3: Keyed<StringExtended, number>;
toNameOf(k3, { foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar' });
toNameOf(k3, {});
toNameOf(k3, { foo: 'Foo' });
toNameOf(k3, { bar: 'Bar' });
```

The `k1` cases correctly fail unless we get a `names` argument that actually covers all of the possibilities. And in `k2`, we just reject everything; `k2` doesn’t have a type that `toNamesOf` supports. But in the `k3` cases, however, all compile with no error or warning, despite my best efforts. And structures analogous to `Keyed` that are filled (correctly, in other use-cases) with `StringExtended` rather than any particular literal are everywhere in our code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that I consider sufficiently robust. It doesn’t cover the fourth bullet point, but as noted, that was less important to me.

```
type LikeLiteralUnion<K extends string | number | symbol> =
    string extends K ? never :
    number extends K ? never :
    symbol extends K ? never :
    [{}] extends [{ [P in K]: unknown; }] ? never :
    K;
```

I had noted in the question that when you used a mixin, e.g. `type K = string & { extension(): void; }`, `{ [P in K]: unknown; }` is inferred as `{}` rather than `{ [P: string]: unknown; }`. That turns out to be a distinction between the two that we can leverage.

Use like

```
declare function takeLiteralUnion<K extends string | number | symbol>(k: LikeLiteralUnion<K>): void;
```